# website layout in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I could use some help. Im new to illustrator and I'm supposed to make a website layout with my illustrator designs I already have (logos, brochures, posters, maps,,,etc). But I don't have clear information on how to do that. How do I import my .AI designs on the layout? When I do place them and minimize them a bit they become a mess, plus the file itself becomes over 120MB in size, and would think that is not right. Do I need to place them as an image or? I am really confused and really need some help.Thank you

Comment: Hi Emily. Your question is very broad and would probably be better asked as a number of questions or narrowed to a more specific question. You can read through the [help] to find out what is on and off-topic and how to ask a good question.

Comment: One thing I will say is that 120mb isn't actually a very large file at all

Comment: @CAI Well as you can see I am very confused:) So, I made a website layout template on illustrator.Now I am supposed to present my 6 illustrator artworks on that layout. (i have one logo, a map, poster, brochure, graphs and video game box design). My question is-how do I do that? Do i Just place the artwork in .ai format, or I should save for the web all 6 first, and than place it on the layout? I have never done this before and it wasn't really explained to me, so I am trying to figure this one on my own...Thank you!

Comment: @Emily - Just copy and paste the artwork from your other Illustrator files into the website design file and adjust the pasted artwork to size. This is basic Illustrator/design tool stuff. Don't worry about file size(s) until its time to actually export graphic assets for use in the website development.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option would be to Export the Adobe Illustrator files to a PNG format (this ensures transparency is kept). Then I would suggest using Adobe Photoshop to create your website layout. You would need to set up the document type as either the iMac artboard or the 1024x768px resolution depending on which device you are working with. For mobile devices I suggest that you use a resolution of 320x480px. You can then add your exported PNG files into that web layout without any issues.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution and welcome to GraphicDesign!